# Bash remove first and last characters from a string

Tags: bash, command-line, scripts

I have a string like that:

```
|abcdefg|
```

And I want to get a new string called in someway (like string2) with the original string without the two `|` characters at the start and at the end of it so that I will have this:

```
abcdefg
```

Is that possible in bash?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can do

```
string="|abcdefg|"
string2=${string#"|"}
string2=${string2%"|"}
echo $string2
```

Or if your string length is constant, you can do

```
string="|abcdefg|"
string2=${string:1:7}
echo $string2
```

Also, this should work

```
echo "|abcdefg|" | cut -d "|" -f 2
```

Also this

```
echo "|abcdefg|" | sed 's/^|\(.*\)|$/\1/'
```

Comment: and also `awk -F\| '{ print $2 }' <<<"|string|"`

Comment: @enzotib You always have cool `awk` solutions. I need to learn `awk`.

Comment: and also `IFS='|' read string2 <<< $string` :)

Comment: and also, in bash 4.2 and newer, `"${string:1:-1}"`

Comment: Read under the "parameter expansion" section in `man bash`.

Answer (score 81):

Here's a solution that is independent of the length of the string (bash):

```
string="|abcdefg|"
echo "${string:1:${#string}-2}"
```

Answer (score 65):

Going off a few posts listed here it seems the simplest way to do it is:

```
string="|abcdefg|"
echo ${string:1:-1}
```

edit: works on ubuntu with bash 4.2; does not work on centOS with bash 4.1

Comment: This should be have been the top answer. You won't find any bash 4.1 on modern systems. :)

Comment: The first `1` in this answer represents how many characters are dropped from the start, The second `1` represents how many characters are dropped from the end. So echo `echo ${string:2:-3}` would yield output:`bcde`.

Answer (score 32):

Another way is to use `head` & `tail` commands:

```
$ echo -n "|abcdefg|" | tail -c +2 | head -c -2
abcdefg
```

Comment: I had a string of `[something something]` with a goal to cut brackets, so `echo "[something something]" | tail -c +2 | head -c -2` worked out. Thanks for a tip!

Comment: Obviously, it should be `echo -n "|abcdefg|" | tail -c +2 | head -c -1`. I'm not sure why my edits were rejected... It's very sad, to be honest. See `man head` for more info

Comment: Best answer, does what was requested with the most simple tools and is not dependent on extra factors like char is x, y or z.

Comment: Not working on the latest shell editions (at least on mac...).
I get `head: illegal byte count -- -2`

Answer (score 11):

You can also use sed to remove the | not just referencing the symbol itself but using positional references as in:

```
$ echo "|abcdefg|" | sed 's:^.\(.*\).$:\1:'
abcdefg
```

Where ':' are the delimiters (you can replace them with / or  any character not in the query, any sign following the s will do it) Here ^ (caret) means at the beginning of the input string and $ (dollar) means at the end. The . (point) that it's after the caret and the one that it's before the dollar sign represents a single character. So in other words we are deleting the first and last characters.
Take in mind this will delete any characters even if | it's not present in the string.

EX:

```
$ echo "abcdefg" | sed 's:^.\(.*\).$:\1:'
bcdef
```

Answer (score 10):

And another one:

```
string="|abcdefg|"
echo "${string//|/}"
```

Answer (score 3):

#### shell function

A bit more verbose approach, but works on any sort of first and last character, doesn't have to be the same. Basic idea is that we are taking a variable, reading it character by character, and appending only those 
we want to a new variable

Here's that whole idea formatted into  a nice function

```
crop_string_ends() {
    STR="$1" 
    NEWSTR="" 
    COUNT=0 
    while read -n 1 CHAR 
    do
        COUNT=$(($COUNT+1)) 
        if [ $COUNT -eq 1 ] || [ $COUNT -eq ${#STR} ] 
        then
            continue 
        fi 
        NEWSTR="$NEWSTR"$CHAR 
    done <<<"$STR" 
    echo $NEWSTR 
}
```

And here is that same function in action:

```
$> crop_string_ends "|abcdefg|"                                                                                       
abcdefg
$> crop_string_ends "HelloWorld"                                                                                      
elloWorl
```

#### Python

```
>>> mystring="|abcdefg|"
>>> print(mystring[1:-1])
abcdefg
```

or on command line:

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print sys.stdin.read()[1:-2]' <<< "|abcdefg|"                                             
abcdefg
```

#### AWK

```
$ echo "|abcdefg|" | awk '{print substr($0,2,length($0)-2)}'                                                      
abcdefg
```

#### Ruby

```
$ ruby -ne 'print $_.split("|")[1]' <<< "|abcdefg|"                                                               
abcdefg
```

Answer (score 2):

Small and universal solution:

```
expr "|abcdef|" : '.\(.*\).'
```

Special in this case and allowing that the '|' character may be there or not:

```
expr "|abcdef" : '|*\([^|]*\)|*'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ string="|abcdefg|"
$ string="${string#?}" && string="${string%%?}"
$ echo "$string"
abcdefg
```

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

> **`${var#Pattern}`**
>   Remove from `$var` the *shortest* part of `$Pattern` that matches the *front end* of `$var`.
>   **`${var%%Pattern}`**
>   Remove from `$var` the *longest* part of `$Pattern` that matches the *back end* of `$var`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
echo "|abcdefg|" | tr -d "|"
```

With this line of code, you remove all ***|***->(pipe) in the string.

Comment: I needed to remove dbl-quotes from a `grep`d string (e.g. "IPVanish-nyca20-VPN"). The `| tr -d "\""` worked like a charm. +1

Comment: Surprising that this is the **only** answer here that recommends `tr`; even more surprising that this is the **first** answer - after 13 years - to use `tr` in the answer. Hmmm - maybe that says something about Ubuntu (or its users)  lol      Anyway, here's [more on `tr` from Dave McKay](https://www.howtogeek.com/886723/how-to-use-the-linux-tr-command/).